# Current week in current month showing wrong in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

This is how the July month looks like.

[image]

I am trying to pick the current week in current month with `getdate()` parameter using the below code.

```
declare @date datetime = getdate()
select datepart(day, datediff(day, 0, @date) / 7 * 7) / 7 + 1
```

Expecting the result as

```
Date       -> week Number
2015-07-01 -> 1
2015-07-06 -> 2
2015-07-13 -> 3
```

But, instead, the result is:

```
Date       -> week Number
2015-07-01 -> 5
2015-07-06 -> 1
2015-07-13 -> 2
```

How do I get the first format in SQL Server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Weeks go by sunday, so 7-01- is in the 5th week of june ...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to get the right answer

```
select datediff(week, dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @date), 0)), 0), @date)+1
```